# Equivalence of format strings '[0-9-+]%' and '[0-9+-]%' using PatIndex

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a function to handle converting formatted strings to relative dates and found that:

```
Select patindex( '[0-9-+]%', '-Y' ) returns 0
```

but

```
Select patindex( '[0-9+-]%', '-Y' ) returns 1
```

I thought that the two format strings were equivalent.

Is `0-9-+` really characters 0 to 9 to +?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please click above my name/image where it says edited to see how I changed your post to look like it does. If you format questions correctly, they are easier to read and likely to get a better response. If you click on the `edit` link, between `share` and `close` you can see the actual new formatting that has been applied.

Comment: The grammar for the pattern syntax isn't very well described or documented when it comes to having anything other than a simple range or simple set inside the square brackets. I found before that behaviour can change when using the same pattern with VarChar vs nvarchar. My singularly unsuccessful attempt at reporting this was at https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/742841/pattern-syntax-undocumented-difference-in-behaviour-between-varchar-vs-nvarchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have a pattern enclosed in square brackets, any dash operators that are entered between any two characters means a match on all characters between and including those two characters in the sort order of the collation, which for most standard characters matches the order in the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/). However, a character can not be the start- and endpoint of two different intervals:

```
[0-9]    -- Obviously matches 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
[9-+]    -- Matches nothing, since 9 follows after + in an ascii table.
[+-9]    -- Matches + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
[0-9-+]  -- Doesn't work, since two dash operators use the same endpoint twice.
         -- Instead, it seems that the parser interprets this as [09+].
[0-99-+] -- Means the same as [0-9] since + comes before 9 in the ascii table,
         -- so the second interval [9-+] matches nothing.
```

However, when a dash operator is next to a square bracket, it is included in the match:

```
[-]      -- Matches the - character.
[-0-9]   -- Matches the - character, and also 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
[0-9+-]  -- Mathces 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 + -
```

Comment: Ranges use the sort order of the collation. Not necessarily ascii order.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith - updated my answer to clarify this point.